# Chrome Applying Unwanted Margin-Top

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, debugging, browser

My site working well on all browsers and devices -- with the exception of Google Chrome on a large screen, which applies a margin-top of somewhere around 200-300px. I have been trying to debug using the Chrome Console but I haven't seen any differences in the source code. Has anyone else experienced this? Below is the spacing for the elements in question.([Chrome Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvvNm.png))([Firefox Working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg2RN.png))([View Page Here](https://kjwall.com/writings.html))

```
.column {
 flex: 50%;
 display: flex;
 /*height: 100vh;*/
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
```

}

```
.colone {
   height: 100vh;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
```

}

Comment: For me using Google Chrome it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: are you on a laptop? Because it is also fine for me on a laptop screen. Only on my 22" desktop monitor does it get out of position

Comment: For me it works perfectly fine on Google Chrome at 4K resolution. (3860x2160)